# Unable to extract Name from text in R

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I am trying to figure out what regex to use to extract the name from text. Each name has a first initial, a period, and last name followed by what seems to be a code for space () which for some reason shows up when I uploaded the csv to R.

Here are four examples of how the text is laid out:

```
D. Nowitzki<U+00A0>misses 2-pt jump shot from 17 ft
J. Calderon<U+00A0>misses 2-pt jump shot from 12 ft
Turnover by<U+00A0>M. Ellis<U+00A0>(bad pass; steal by<U+00A0>T. 
Splitter)
```

Defensive rebound byS. Marion

```
    data$Player <- sub("(.*\\..*)<", "\\1", data$Play)

    data$Player <- sub("(.*\\..*)<", "\\1", data$Play)
```

Comment: Try `stringr::str_extract(data$Play, "\\b\\p{Lu}\\.\\s*\\w+")`

Comment: Wow. Presto. Thank you so much. For my learning, can you explain to me where I went wrong and what {Lu} is in regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pattern, `(.*\..*)<`, captures into Group 1 any 0+ chars as many as possible, then a `.` char,  then any 0+ chars as many as possible and then a `<` is matched. So, you match quite a lot of text and it is not quite clear if `<U+00A0>` is a literal text or if it is an entity standing for a non-breaking space in your data. If the latter is true, your pattern is just not matching because there is no `<`.

I assume you want to extract the first match starting with a letter as a whole word followed with a dot, then any 0 or more whitespaces and then 1+ letters. Hence, you may use

```
\b\p{Lu}\.\s*\p{L}+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Jo77oj/1).

**Details**

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `\p{Lu}` - any uppercase Unicode letter
  -`\.` - a dot
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\p{L}+` - any 1+ Unicode letters

In R, you may easily use the pattern with `stringr::str_extract` that extracts the first match only:

```
res <- stringr::str_extract(data$Play, "\\b\\p{Lu}\\.\\s*\\p{L}+")
```